# How a browser can reach the server without doing postback?

Tags: asp.net, .net

i've been asked this question and id not know the answer.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You mean using ajax or something, your question is need more informations, how and what you like to do ?

Comment: Its theoretical question from job interview

Comment: Remove then the `master` from your nick name because is holding you back from your evolution. (do not place even the slave :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Postback* is a term used often in ASP.NET when a WebForm POSTs the single form back to the server and invokes some event in the code behind (like a click on a button for example). You could still use normal GET requests though to redirect to a given web page. For example you could use an anchor:

```
<a href="/page2.aspx?param=somevalue">Go to page 2</a>
```

When the user clicks on the anchor there is no postback occuring but a GET request to the target web page.

Another possibility is the user typing directly the address of the web page in his browser address bar.

Yet another possibility is to use javascript to perform an AJAX request which allows to invoke a web page without redirecting away from the current page. You could use any HTTP verb with AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to categories the call to the server you can say that there are two types.

The `GET` and the `POST`

The `POST` is the post back and are the parameters that you send using a `form`

and the `GET` that are the parameters that you can send from the url.

More about:
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html
http://thinkvitamin.com/code/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post/
http://catcode.com/formguide/getpost.html

but I think the interview question was about the Ajax call, and this is probably what they try to see if you know, how to use Ajax to reach the server with javascript and not make postback. But you need to know that Ajax can make POST back, but this is done with out leave the page, with out make a full page post back.

Answer (score 1):

We can use javascript code to do some function without postback. This will save the time for the request and response to the server. But this client side. you can't reach the server without posting back.But my mean you can do functionality by javascript which does not postback the page.

Hope it may help.